# Postgres table partitioning not improving query speed

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-partitioning

I have a query that's run on a table (TABLE_A) that's partitioned by recTime……

```
WITH subquery AS ( 
select count(*) AS cnt, date_trunc('day',recTime) AS recTime 
from TABLE_A 
WHERE (recTime >= to_timestamp('2018-Nov-03 00:00:00','YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
   AND recTime <= to_timestamp('2018-Nov-03 23:59:59','YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
GROUP BY date_trunc('day',recTime) 
) 
UPDATE sumDly 
SET fixes = subquery.cnt 
FROM subquery 
WHERE 
  sumDly.Day = subquery.recTime
```

If I do an *explain* on the query as shown above it's apparent that the database is doing an index scan on each of the partition in the parent table. The associated cost is high and the elapsed time is ridiculous.

If I explicitly force the use of the partition that actually has the data in by replacing….

```
 from TABLE_A
```

With….

```
from TABLE_A_20181103
```

Then the *explain* only uses the required partition, and the query takes only a few minutes (and the returned results are the same as before)

**QUESTION** - Why does the database want to scan all the partitions in the table? I though the whole idea of partitioning was to help the database eliminate vast swathes of unneeded data in the first pass rather than forcing a scan on all the indexes in individual partitions?

---

UPDATE - I am using version 10.5 of postgres

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: There can't be anything sophisticated in `WHERE` clause. Anything more complicated than simple comparison won't work. You have to prepare correct timestamps upfront i.e. `... WHERE recTime >= '2018-11-03 00:00:00'`.

Comment: @Jakub Fedyczak - yup, that did the trick. Thank you! It never occurred to me that to_timestamp() counts as 'sophisticated'

Answer (score 0):

`SET constraint_exclusion = on` and make sure to hard-code the constraints into the query. Note that you have indeed hard-coded the constrains in the query:

```
...
WHERE (recTime >= to_timestamp('2018-Nov-03 00:00:00','YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
   AND recTime <= to_timestamp('2018-Nov-03 23:59:59','YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
...
```